# loading cscope database in emacs

Tags: emacs, cscope

I want to use cscope in emacs. Due to my directory structure i only want to use files from certain subdirectories in the tree.
In the shell i create my cscope.files list (includes a listing of all the source files i want)
the i do:

```
cscope -q -R -b -i cscope.files
```

This will create the cscope.out file i want. Now i want to read this file into emacs to use it for source code parsing etc ...

So the question is:
How do i have emacs load it? It seems that all the options i get (ie M-x cscope-wahtever) are for creating a new cscope.out file.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

i guess i am answering my own question.
So the problem was not exactly with cscope.
First, in order to point cscope to the database file one set the initial directory:

```
M-x cscope-set-initial-directory
```

to where the cscope database is located.

However, it appears that the input file from which the database is constructed needs to have relative paths in it (or the initial directory need to be pointing to '/'). I had absolute paths in it and thus nothing was found after setting the initial directory to the source root.